# BASH: batch rename files with infix

Tags: bash, mv

I have files `'/my/file_{01...10}.mat'` that I'd like to rename to `'/my/file_ABC{01..10}.mat'` such that `'file_01.mat'` becomes `'file_ABC01.mat', 'file_02.mat' > 'file_ABC02.mat',...` and so on.

I've found a number of ways to append strings in a script but nothing (that I understand) to infix strings. Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for f in /my/file_*.mat; do mv $f ${f/_/_ABC}; done
```